# Why isn't the isSame method from momentjs working correctly when timezones are used?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use the `isSame` method from momentjs. When I use it without a timezone, it works as expected:

```js
var now = moment();

console.log(
   now.format(),
   now.isSame('2020-01-02', 'day')
);
```

Since today is 2020-01-02, when the code runs, it logs:

`2020-01-02T14:56:22-05:00 true`

Now I run almost the same code, using moment timezone:

```js
var nowTz = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');

console.log(
    nowTz.format(),
    nowTz.isSame('2020-01-02', 'day')
);
```

Now, the code logs:

`2020-01-02T12:56:22-07:00 false`

Is this a bug? In the second example, why is the library telling me the moments are not for the same day? Here is a jsfiddle demoing the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/fytw17va/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because moment is creating your `2020-01-02` date implicitly at `00:00`, and then when it's compared to a timezone-aware datetime, it's shifted from midnight of the browser's timezone to the equivalent time in Los Angeles, which could be during `2020-01-01`.

For example,

```
> console.log(moment('2020-01-02').format())
"2020-01-02T00:00:00-05:00"
> console.log(moment('2020-01-02').tz('America/Los_Angeles').format())
"2020-01-01T22:00:00-07:00"
```

To avoid this, you can explicitly construct a timezone-aware object with the correct date of `2020-01-02`, and then use this for your isSame checks:

```
today = moment.tz('2020-01-02', 'America/Los_Angeles')
nowTz = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles');

console.log(
    nowTz.format(),
    nowTz.isSame(today, 'day')
);
```

Which logs something like `2020-01-02T13:44:05-07:00 true`